# How to remove email validation in opencart 2.1 for register account form?

Tags: javascript, ajax, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I am trying to register customer with phone number instead of email ID so would like to remove email address validation

Thanks!!

Comment: I have found [this discussion on opencart.com](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=28155) that tells how to do it.

Comment: Thanks!!! Saved my Day

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

In `catalog/controller/checkout/register.php`

find (line 149):

```
if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['email']) > 96) || !filter_var($this->request->post['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $json['error']['email'] = $this->language->get('error_email');
}
```

and comment it out.

In `catalog/controller/checkout/guest.php`

find  (line 203):

```
if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['email']) > 96) || !filter_var($this->request->post['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $json['error']['email'] = $this->language->get('error_email');
}
```

and comment it out.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Hi @IvanIvanov - welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question to say "comment it out" rather than posting the whole commented code.